# Davening musaf alone on Rosh Chodesh

Tags: tefilin, rosh-chodesh-new-month, hefsek-interruption, musaf

Normally on Rosh Chodesh, people in most shuls I've seen take off their tefillin after kaddish, but don't wrap them.  This is also what Artscroll nusach Ashkenaz says.

What about if you daven alone and there's no kaddish?  If you follow this minhag, should you wrap your tefillin?  We seem not to be too concerned about hefsek between ashrei(+uva letziyon) and shemoneh esrei, since at shacharit we put kriyat shema between pesukei dezimra, which is the extension of ashrei, and shemoneh esrei, and at mincha on Shabbos and fast days we put leining in between.

On the other hand, we do announce things (משיב הרוח, יעלה ויבא, ...) between kaddish and shemoneh esrei instead of before kaddish, so maybe there's something more subtle happening with regard to wrapping tefillin that I'm not appreciating.

Comment: It should be noted that many strongly opposed waiting until after Kaddish to remove Tefillin, and many also strongly opposed not wrapping Tefillin immediately upon their removal. It's highly likely the 'custom' you refer to is in fact based on applying a typo in a text to a Nusach haTefillah we don't even follow.

Comment: Artscroll says to remove them but not to wrap them?  I have to go look at that, because I've never noticed that before.  What page?

Comment: @SethJ I didn't believe it either. It's at the beginning of Musaf for RC (like 660 or so). And that's how bad Minhagim catch on...

Comment: Conversation about various practices regarding removing Tefillin on Rosh Chodesh has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39513/discussion-on-question-by-heshy-davening-musaf-alone-on-rosh-chodesh).

Comment: In fact, the old Minhog Ashkenaz is to keep the Tefillin on until after Oleinu, even on Rosh Chodesh and Chol HaMo'eid.

Answer (score 2):

The discussion of what one is supposed to do [Rosh Chodesh: Removing Tefillin](http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/10/rosh-chodesh-removing-tefillin/) seems, based on the meforshim cited in the footnotes, that the reason is that one does not delay (after the chazan removes his tefillin) because of hefsek after kaddish and tircha detziburah. Also, that everyone should start at the same time as the tzibur. The implication would seem to be that when davening alone, one should not delay wrapping (at least) the tefillin. ([16] Mishna Berura 28:8.)

On the other hand. many people begin removing their tefillin before kaddish so that they can finish before everyone starts shmoneh esrai.

> As one will notice, widespread custom is to remove the tefillin after
>   the kaddish that follows “uva l’tzion“.[8] Once the tefillin are
>   removed they are usually just placed on a table and not properly put
>   away and in most cases they are not even wrapped up. The reason for
>   this is in order to minimize the interruption between the kaddish and
>   the start of Mussaf.[9] Nevertheless, the tefillin should at least be
>   covered before one begins Mussaf.[10]
>
> Although this approach is normative and based on kabbalisitc
>   considerations,[12] there is reason to suggest that it might not be
>   the ideal manner in which to conduct onself. According to a number of
>   authorities the tefillin should be removed while reciting uva l’tzion,
>   just before beginning the yehi ratzon paragraph.[13] Other sources
>   seem to indicate that the tefillin should be removed after completing
>   uva l’tzion but before the kaddish is recited.[14] Indeed, this
>   approach is consistent with other occasions when there is some form of
>   an interruption before Mussaf. For example, in most congregations the
>   rabbi delivers the Shabbat morning drasha *before* the kaddish is
>   recited. In this way, Mussaf can commence immediately after the
>   kaddish with no interruptions.[15]
>
> [13] Mishna Berura 25:59.
>
> [14] Siddur Baal Hatanya.
>
> [15] Mishna Berura 25:59.

Comment: This is roughly just your assertion that the OP's speculation is reasonable. I happen to agree, but a more explicit source would be better, I think.

Comment: @DoubleAA The sources that i found all spoke about with a minyon. As a result, without a minyon had to be by implication.

Comment: FWIW, My shul removes tefillin before Kaddish. People wrap their tefillin, then, also. The 2nd part, (wrapping) is something I don't quite agree with, b/c the extra delay seems to be an incentive for people to schmooze.

Comment: @DanF What about the shaliach tzibur? Does he also remove his tefilling before sayin kaddish?

Comment: @sabbahillel Absolutely. I'm not sure why there would be a difference?

Comment: @DanF In some shuls, people start removing their tefillin as they finish Uva Letzion but the chazan does so after saying kaddish. he then removes his tefillin (putting on the batim but not wrapping them) and gives a klap so everyone starts smone esrai together.

Comment: @sabbahillel I got it. The shul minyan is mainly Conservative people. People, including the chazzan, wait until after the Torah is returned (they do this after Uva Letziyon), and the gabbai announces, "You may remove your tefillin, now." They remove and wrap it (and, sadly, schmooze a little). Then the gabbai announces the page for Chatzi Kaddish and we proceed.

Comment: I hadn't thought of tircha detzibura.  It's an interesting application, because it seems that the only real tircha is for women and boys under bar mitzva (the men are going to have to wrap their tefillin at some point anyway), and in many cases they only make up a small fraction of the tzibbur.

Comment: @Heshy The tircha detzibura is that the chazan takes off his tefillin after kadish and does not wrap them but starts shmona esrai as quickly as possible so that the tzibur (who may have wrapped already) do not have to wait to start .